# No touch events on child view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Alright so I am trying to create a slide out side view for navigation in my app, similar to Facebook and many others.  I have that part working but the navigation controller doesn't respond to any touch events.  I have a feeling this is because I am having my subclassed Navigation Controller add the child view controller and subview, instead of having the present view display the child.  Here is the code I run on my "FeaturedViewController" that calls to "MainNavigationController" to add "MenuViewController" as a child of "MainNavigationController"

```
//ignoring compiler error as we know the parentViewController will be of type MainNavigationController at runtime.
MainNavigationController *main = self.parentViewController;
if (self.categories != nil)
    main.categories = self.categories;

if (main.showingLeftPanel)
    [main movePanelToOriginalPosition];
else
    [main movePanelRight];
```

From there:

```
- (void)movePanelRight // to show left panel
{
UIView *childView = [self getLeftView];
//_leftPanelViewController.categories = self.categories;
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:childView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:SLIDE_TIMING delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     _centerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - PANEL_WIDTH, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {

                         //_centerViewController.leftButton.tag = 0;
                     }
                 }];
}

- (UIView *)getLeftView
{
// init view if it doesn't already exist
if (_leftPanelViewController == nil)
{
    // this is where you define the view for the left panel
    _leftPanelViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];

    [self addChildViewController:_leftPanelViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_leftPanelViewController.view];
    [_leftPanelViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    _leftPanelViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
_leftPanelViewController.categories = self.categories;
self.showingLeftPanel = YES;

// set up view shadows
[self showCenterViewWithShadow:YES withOffset:-2];

UIView *view = self.leftPanelViewController.view;
return view;
}
```

Comment: Have a try 'IIViewDeck' https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck

Comment: I ended up stopping the fight and just made a root view for my navcontroller then swiped from there and it all works fine now.